# Match First and Last names on separate sheets in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, spreadsheet, lookup

I want to match first and last names which are in separate columns and in separate sheets in an excel file. Below is the sample of data:

Sheet 1:

```
First Name      Last Name

Kevin             Durant
Micheal           Jordan
```

Sheet 2:

```
First Name        Last Name
Mike              Ashley
Kevin             Durant
```

In the output, I need to get those first and last names which are in Sheet-2 but not in Sheet-1. I did the research and found this vlookup formula but I have not implemented it since I could not understand how to modify it:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'Names-2'!$A$2:$A$19,1,FALSE)
```

I found it from this link:[vlookup](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3405-excel-vlookup-to-compare-two-sheets.html)

Any help would be great for me to understand vlookups. Thank you

Comment: Is the `Michael` on sheet 1 and `Mike` on sheet 2 actually different? For text, you will need exact matches (not case sensitive)

Comment: @urdearboy yes they are different names.

Comment: What's the desired output for your sample data?

Comment: @SangbokLee in the output I need the first and last names that are in sheet-2 but not in sheet-1. output can be shown on sheet 1 or on sheet 2 where the vlookup is applied.

Comment: So you want `Kevin Durant` in this case?

Comment: @SangbokLee it will be Mike Ashley because it is present in sheet-2 but not in sheet-1

Comment: had you tried the examples in the vlookup help and documentation ? | If you're looking for alternative method, try https://exceljet.net/index-and-match | btw, I had noticed something about your question.. you'd mentioned the source is Sheet 1 & Sheet 2, but may I know the name of each sheet..and in which cell does the data located ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding helper columns will be helpful.

1. Fill `C2:C999` on both sheets with `=A2&" "&B2`.
2. Fill `D2:D999` on `Sheet2` with `=IFERROR(MATCH(C2, Sheet1!C:C, 0), "no")`.
3. Fill `E2:E999` on `Sheet2` with `=IF(D2="no", C2, "")`.

The output column is `E` on `Sheet2`. Sample Excel file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/08jj1es0b9hzahd/59297535.xlsx?dl=0).